# How to generate a new number each time my program loops?

Tags: c

I'm trying to right a program in C where I have to ask the user a certain multiplication question, I'm using rand() to generate the numbers.

If the user gets the answer wrong, then they will be asked to enter it again once they get it right, when they do get it right, the program should loop and ask the user a different question.
I'm using a separate function to generate the answer each time the 2 random values are passed to that function.

My problem is that once I get the answer correct, the program loops and asks the same question, it picks the same number! so how do I make it that everytime it loops, it picks a different number?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int x = rand()%20;
    int y = rand()%20;
    int i, answer;
    i = multiply(x,y);

    do {
        printf("what is %d multiplied by %d?:", x, y);
        scanf("%d", &answer);

        while(answer != i)
        {
            printf("wrong try again!");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
        }

        printf("very good!\n");
    } while(i==answer);

}

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    int k;
    k=x*y;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Your do-do is in the wrong place! Put if after `srand`

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the assignments of `x` and `y` into the loop. This way they will get a new value in each round. In fact, you can move their whole definition in there.

Moreover, the loop coondition `while(i==answer)` is superfluous as at that point it is always going to be true. For the sake of clarity, you should replace it with `true` to make it explicit that it is an infinite loop. (And you may want to extend your program with a way to exit gracefully, e.g. if `'q'` or an empty string is entered - but I will leave this as an exercise for you :-).

```
 while(true) {
  int x = rand()%20;
  int y = rand()%20;
  int i, answer;
  i = multiply(x,y);

  printf("what is %d multiplied by %d?:", x, y);
  scanf("%d", &answer);

  while(answer != i)
  {
    printf("wrong try again!");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
  }

  printf("very good!\n");
}
```

Comment: im getting these errors
multi.c: In function ‘main’:
multi.c:26:10: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
multi.c:26:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
multi.c:26:13: error: ‘answer’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: i moved the declaration of i and answer outside, now it works fine. thanks :)

Comment: @user1304516, sorry, that was an omission. See my updated code sample, it resolves this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Abstractly, your logic should go like this:

```
// seed random number generator

while (true)  // ask infinitely many questions
{
    int x, y, expected_result;  // populate randomly

    printf("Please compute the result of %d and %d: ", x, y);

    while (read_answer() != expected_result)
    {
         printf("Sorry, wrong answer. Try again: ");
    }
}
```

That is, for each question you generate new parameters.

You just need to implement `read_answer()` as a helper function that reads one integer from the input, e.g. using `fgets` and `strtol`.